# Can there be two sequences that are sub-sequences of each-other, but not identical.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have spent days thinking about it. I know that it is possible. 
I can let 
$x=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and 
$y=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.

Now the sequences are different, but I am not sure if $x$ is still the subsequence of $y$. I would accept any help towards this problem.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: *Finite* sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, consider $\{1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots\}$ and $\{2,1,2,1,2,1,\ldots\}$.